# Hadoop MR job on windows: Cannot initialize Cluster, but starting from Idea

Tags: hadoop

Windows 10, Hadoop 3.0.0 from winutils project. Map reduce job working fine from IDE (Intellij Idea), but failing from windows command line (fat jar):

```
java -jar target/app1-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar "E://folderin" "E://folderout" -Xmx8g
```

Return error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Cannot initialize Cluster. Please check your configuration for mapreduce.framework.name and the correspond server addresses.
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Cluster.initialize(Cluster.java:116)
```

In env variables HADOOP_HOME=c:\Hadoop, pom file:

```
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>hadoop-client</artifactId>
            <version>${hadoop.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>com.sample.app1.Starter</mainClass>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>

                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>make-assembly</id>
                        <phase>install</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>

            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

IntellJ Idea put .m2 folder into class path, that is why the job worked from Idea. The issue resolved by adding hadoop libraries in pom.xml:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-client</artifactId>
        <version>${hadoop.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-mapreduce-client-common</artifactId>
        <version>${hadoop.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-mapreduce-client-app</artifactId>
        <version>${hadoop.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-mapreduce-client-jobclient</artifactId>
        <version>${hadoop.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-mapreduce-client-shuffle</artifactId>
        <version>${hadoop.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```